# MeilieSearch Error On Shared Hosting (CentOS - Red Hat) (/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found)

Tags: centos, glibc, meilisearch

I'm unable to setup MeilieSearch on a Shared Hosting (I'm not root).

Error I get:

```php
./meilisearch: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by ./meilisearch)
```

I think the issue is with a library `(GLIBC_2.18)`,
after some research I figured my hosting provider is using `GLIBC_2.17`

Can't we just download this library on our local directory, like: `~/CustomDIR`.

and get get MeilieSearch started by using the locally downloaded Library, so it won't affect any other scripts/services.

Server Info:

```php
// ldd --version         returned this..
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.


// cat /proc/version     returned this..
Linux version 3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.60.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@imagebuilder.corp.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Jul 23 07:07:00 EDT 2021
```

I'm couldn't find any solution in past 2 days :(

Answer (score 0):

> I think the issue is with a library

No. The issue is that your binary: `meilisearch` was built on a machine with GLIBC-2.18 (or later) and you are now running it on a machine with older GLIBC.

The proper fix is to either find a build which can run against GLIBC-2.17, or to build the binary from source on a machine with GLIBC-2.17 (or older).

> Can't we just download this library on our local directory,

Well, why didn't you try?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) explains why that wouldn't work, and what to do instead.